# Error In Embed Script Into Page: 'Failed to execute 'write' '

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am just try inject JW player into the page but I keep getting the error:

> 14 Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

My code is as follows:

```
<html>

<body>
    <div id="jw-live"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = new URL(window.location);
    var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://content.jwplatform.com/players/"+ id +".js";
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;

    window.document.getElementById("jw-live").appendChild(script);

</script>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?